# How to pass some parameters in Url.Action in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url.action

```
Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = 8,name="rachel",grade="a"}));
```

When I get parameters in controller, I get just the first value of "id",
but I didn't get the values of "name" and "grade".

why?

Comment: We need a [mcve].  As is your question is not answerable.  Show us your code.

Comment: This should generate the value like `yourSite/person/createperson/8?name=rachel&grade=a;`. Are you saying it is not generating the querystring like that ?

Comment: No!! the value like this yourSite/person/createperson/8?name=rachel&amp;grade=a; what is the amp that it add???

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("CreatePerson","Person",new{id=8,name="rachel",grade="a"}) try this..

Answer (score 0):

Just do this instead (no route value dictionary needed):

```
Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new { id = 8,name="rachel",grade="a"});
```

Verify the URL contains all of the parameters via the `Request.Url` property in the controller (via breakpoint) to make sure it has all the parameters.

Comment: I did it.but when I got the values - I did gat the values of name and grade just the value of id. Why????

Comment: @Rachel See my comment on your question.  We cannot answer your question without guessing blindly.  Please add code to your question.  What does `CreatePerson` look like?  How are your routes defined?

Comment: $("#divMain").load("/Home/q?r=9&amp;c=3");

Comment: I wrote the next code in js:        function f1()
        {
             $("#divMain").load("@Url.Action("q", "Home",new { r=9,c=3})");
        }

Comment: I wrote the next code in js:
        function f1()
        {
             $("#divMain").load("@Url.Action("q", "Home",new { r=9,c=3})");
        }
when I do debbug I see that it translate to next url
"/Home/q?r=9&amp;c=3"

what is the "amp" that it wrote?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("CreatePerson","Person",new{id=8,name="rachel",grade="a"}) try this..

Comment: @Rachel I do this all the time and it works for me.  You have to use the debugging features to inspect why it's not finding the other two parameters.  Examine the URL, and the Routing Parameters, to see what is going on.

Comment: @Rachel See my comment on your question. We cannot answer your question without guessing blindly. Please add code to your question. What does CreatePerson look like? How are your routes defined?